# Swift Multiple Tableview Textfield Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am looking to create three tableview textfield cells and I'm trying to figure out the mechanics behind creating this. So far I have created a public class that holds my textfield outlets and a configuration function passing values to outlet properties, but I'm stumped as to how I should be passing these rows to the tableview especially when it comes to the reuse identifier. How should I achieve this?

UserRegistrationTableViewCells.swift:

```
   import Foundation

    public class UserRegistrationTableViewCells: UITableViewCell {


        @IBOutlet var usernameTextField: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!


        public func configure(#text: String?, placeholder: String){

            usernameTextField.text = text
            usernameTextField.placeholder = placeholder
            usernameTextField.accessibilityValue = text
            usernameTextField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder

            emailTextField.text = text
            emailTextField.placeholder = placeholder
            emailTextField.accessibilityValue = text
            emailTextField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder

            passwordTextField.text = text
            passwordTextField.placeholder = placeholder
            passwordTextField.accessibilityValue = text
            passwordTextField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder


        }
```

UserRegistrationViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class UserRegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var registrationTableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("usernameTextField") as UserRegistrationTableViewCells

        return UITableViewCell()

    }
```

Comment: This question, "how I should be passing these rows to the tableview" is  unclear. What you show in your table view code is correct (as far as it goes), except that the return statement should be `return cell`, not `return UITableViewCell()` .  You need to be setting the initial text of the text views (if that's what you want) in cellForRowAtIndexPath, not in the cell's code. You also need to make the controller the delegate of the text fields and deal with he input from the user when they type in the text fields.

Comment: Hey @rdelmar thanks for the comment. I'm actually questioning my use of the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method. I'm only targeting one of my cell identifiers, but I have three present. This is actually giving me an error message `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` which is located on the `let cell` line. How can I change that to capture all of my cell identifiers?

Comment: You really should use the newer method, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: which doesn't return an optional. If you identifier is correct, then that method should always return a valid cell. If it crashes, then something is wrong with your identifier.

Comment: Okay, but if I have an identifier for each cell, `usernameTextField`, `emailTextField`, `passwordTextField`, wouldn't only calling `usernameTextField` not be enough to properly use this table?

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't be enough. You need to have an if-else clause, and dequeue the cell you want based on the indexPath. Where do you want these 3 different types to appear? In what rows or sections?

Comment: I'm trying to have them appear in the same tableview in the same controller. The purpose of these three cells are to register the values being passed to each individual one. These dynamic cells are acting more like static cells just sitting there

Comment: So what is your question? You do it like I said. You put if-else statements in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, and dequeue the appropriate cell fro the appropriate row. In pseudo code, if indexPath.row == 0 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("usernameTextField"), else if indexPath.row == 1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("emailTextField"), etc. After each dequeue, you do what you need to do in that cell, then return the cell.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion on my end @rdelmar, I have setup the if else statement, but what should I define as `cell` since setting `index = indexPath.row` doesn't work as NSNumber cannot be a subtype of UITableViewCell.

Comment: After looking over your code again, it seems you only have one type of cell (that is cell class); is that correct? If so, you should only have one identifier. I don't really understand what you're trying to do. You have 3 rows, and each cell has a username, email, and password text field. Is that what you want, not 3 rows each of which has only one text field?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have one type of cell class containing three cells that have a text field each. One cell for username, one for email and one for password. I am trying to consolidate my code for these cells within one cell class. Is this not the best way to approach this?

Comment: Well, you don't really need any code in the cell class other than the IBOutlets. Any populating of the text fields should be done in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I would either use a static table view for this, or better yet, not use a table view at all. All you need is 3 labels and 3 text fields in a view. Implement textFieldDidEndEditing: to get the text out of the text fields.